# How to get polymorphic relations with inheritance working in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have the following rails models.

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name ='service'
end

class ChildA < Service
  has_many :charges
end

class ChildB < Service
  self.table_name = "childb_table"
  has_many :charges
end

class Charges < ApplicationRecord
  :belongs_to chargeable, polymorphic: true
end
# code using this
a = ClassB.new.save
charge = Charges.new.save
a.charges.add(a) # this adds the column with the class name 'Service'
```

I try to save the objects but the `chargeable_type` field is always set as the base class `service` and the never the child class.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Shouldn't the `:has_many charges` lines be `has_many :charges`? (Same with the `belongs_to` line) Also, I'm not totally sure what's happening here. Which object are you trying to save? Can you show the code you're using to save an object? I can't be sure with what's pasted here, but you may be looking for STI (https://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your `Service` class as an abstract.

Tested with Rails 5.1

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name ='service'
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Example from: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveRecord%2FInheritance%2FClassMethods%3Aabstract_class

```
class SuperClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Child < SuperClass
  self.table_name = 'the_table_i_really_want'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is in the [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table
>   inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to
>   work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI
>   models in the type column of the polymorphic association. To continue
>   with the asset example above, suppose there are guest posts and member
>   posts that use the posts table for STI. In this case, there must be a
>   type column in the posts table.
>
> Note: The attachable_type= method is being called when assigning an
>   attachable. The class_name of the attachable is passed as a String.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  def attachable_type=(class_name)
     super(class_name.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # because we store "Post" in attachable_type now dependent: :destroy will work
  has_many :assets, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class GuestPost < Post
end

class MemberPost < Post
end
```

Comment: The attachble type is always called with base_class name, I want it to be called using the current class name e.g. "GuestPost"

Comment: Then override the `attachable_type=` method in each sub-class, and have it return the class name you want.

Comment: OK. Why does ChildB inherit from Service? Is it possible to move the shared functionality to a module or concern and avoid using inheritance?

Comment: I can move it to a concern, but it is a huge refactor. Looking for a way without doing that.